# Why doesn't the LED shut off?

Tags: current, control, led-driver

Why doesn't the LED doesn't shut off when I set the input to 0V? The simulation does, but that's not what happens in the real circuit.  I've grounded the second op amp's inputs (on a NE5532), tried using the same 5V supply for the LED, checked, double checked and rechecked the circuit.  The LED is a super bright from Cree. Everything seems within specs for AMR.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ5kSI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: what voltages do you measure at various points?

Comment: Is the MOSFET oriented correct?

Comment: You can't use an NE5532 in that particular circuit.

Comment: Which is it? A NE5532? or a LM358? They're different animals.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Is it the common-mode input range? (+/- 13V on +/-15V supply). I'm reading now the NE5532 also needs +/- 5V minimum supply..  Will try the LM358.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opamp may have a large enough offset voltage so it requires the input voltage to be slightly negative to completely shutoff the LED. It will vary between opamps.

It can be avoided by intentionally giving a few millivolts positive bias to ensure that the LED is turned off when the input is zero.

That can be arranged by adding a resistor between R2 and the opamp negative input and a second resistor from the negative input to +5V.

Another problem that can occur with this type of design is that it can oscillate. This is usually due to the gate capacitance of the MOSFET in conjunction with the output resistance of the opamp causing excessive phase around the feedback loop. This can be cured by separating the high-frequency and low frequency feedback paths.

Comment: Ok.  Spec'd to 0.5mV nom to 4mV max.  So 10-80 uA, not zero.  Will add bias as you suggest. I'll target 10mV for margin.  So the idea is that when input < 10mV-4mV, the op amp can't make that work, so it's output should rail, which should be a hard off on the FET?

Comment: @PiedPiper - that sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

For the NE5532, many reasons.

The input voltage range does not go very near the negative supply. So as your negative supply is the 0V ground, valid input range is upwards from 2 or 3 volts. So in any case, the single ended 5V supply is quite low.

The output voltage range also does not go very close to the negative supply.
So given the circuit, it's not just suitable for this usage.

LM358 input goes down to negative rail. The output can go nearly down to 0V, maybe near few tens of millivolts, but it may require more load than 1Mohm to go that low.

Comment: LM358 output can certainly go close enough to 0V  to turn off a 2N7000 N channel enhancement MOSFET